# issue in writing function to filter rows data frame

Tags: python, pandas, function

I am writing a function that will serve as filter for rows that I wanted to use.
The sample data frame is as follow:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df ['Xstart'] = [1,2.5,3,4,5]
df ['Xend'] = [6,8,9,10,12]
df ['Ystart'] = [0,1,2,3,4]
df ['Yend'] = [6,8,9,10,12]
df ['GW'] = [1,1,2,3,4]

def filter(data,Game_week):
    pass_data = data [(data['GW'] == Game_week)]
```

when I recall the function filter as follow, I got an error.

```
df1 = filter(df,1)
```

The error message is

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'head'
```

but when I use manual filter, it works.

```
pass_data = df [(df['GW'] == [1])]
```

This is my first issue.

My second issue is that I want to filter the rows with multiple GW (1,2,3) etc.

For that I can manually do it as follow:

```
pass_data = df [(df['GW'] == [1])|(df['GW'] == [2])|(df['GW'] == [3])]
```

if I want to use in function input as list [1,2,3]
how can I write it in function such that I can input a range of 1 to 3?

Could anyone please advise?

Thanks,

Zep

Comment: `return data [(data['GW'] == Game_week)]` in `filter()` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for pass list of values instead scalar, also [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#filter) is existing function in python, so better is change function name:

```
def filter_vals(data,Game_week):
    return data[data['GW'].isin(Game_week)]
```

---

```
df1 = filter_vals(df,range(1,4))
```

Comment: I just want to use range of GW for example 1to3 GW.

Comment: Oh I see Jez. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't `return` in the function, so it will be `None`, not the desired dataframe, so do (note that also no need parenthesis inside the `data[...]`):

```
def filter(data,Game_week):
    return data[data['GW'] == Game_week]
```

Also, `isin` may well be better:

```
def filter(data,Game_week):
    return data[data['GW'].isin(Game_week)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `return` to return data from the function for the first part. For the second, use -

```
def filter(data,Game_week):
    return data[data['GW'].isin(Game_week)]
```

Now apply the `filter` function -

```
df1 = filter(df,[1,2])
```